# Nginx server blocks + Multiple SSL Domains + Lets encrypt certificates

Tags: nginx, centos7, lets-encrypt, drupal7

i have a weird situation and its getting to me, here is the situation in a nutshell.

1. website A with domain name: webappA.com
2. website B with domain name: webappB.com

All websites are configured as server blocks on nginx/1.10.2 and https works very fine using Let's encrypt certificates. everything works fine, you access https://webappA.com and https://webappB.com

Now, on to the challenge
every time i do a google search forexample "webappA about", the search results i get include the webappB url, forexample https://webappB.com/about.html

Any help on this, thanks in Advance.
My Environment is centos7+nginx/1.10.2+Drupal7 websites

Comment: Your configuration would be useful. Also are you using Drupal multi-site?

Comment: no, NOT using Drupal multi-site! actually have others drupal sites as vhosts but there are fine. each drupal site is on its own as a website per my client.

Comment: here are my main nginx.conf

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sekayasin/6ac4420dd3a2dcb52adb0aa4e6735391